# User signup Exact Target (Ruby)

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, wsdl, ruby-on-rails

I have been trying to find examples of using the Savon gem with Rails to connect to the SOAP endpoint. Before Exact Target recomended the Fuel SDK but this doesn't seem to be supported anymore. It would of been as simple as following [this](https://github.com/ExactTarget/FuelSDK-Ruby/blob/master/samples/sample-AddSubscriberToList.rb) example.

Anyway, I have a rails app with a newsletter signup form. The signup form takes an email address. I just need to figure out how to call the API to do exactly the same thing as seen in [that example](https://github.com/ExactTarget/FuelSDK-Ruby/blob/master/samples/sample-AddSubscriberToList.rb).

Is there anyplace I can find such info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Savon directly, the following example shows adding a subscriber to a list with a couple profile attributes:

```
require 'savon'
require '../creds.rb' #This is used to set values for $wsdl, $endpoint, $username, and $password

et_client = Savon.client(
    wsdl: $wsdl,
    endpoint: $endpoint,
    wsse_auth: [$username, $password],
    raise_errors: false,
    log: false,
    open_timeout:180,
    read_timeout: 180
  )

subscriber = {}
subscriber['@xsi:type'] = "tns:Subscriber"
subscriber['EmailAddress'] = 'RubyTesting5@bh.exacttarget.com'
subscriber['Lists'] = {'ID' => '1719338'}
subscriber['Attributes'] = [{"Name" =>"First Name", "Value" => "Example"}, {"Name" =>"Last Name", "Value" => "Smith"}]

response = et_client.call(:create, :message => {'Objects' => subscriber})

if !response.nil? then 
    envelope = response.hash[:envelope]

    createresponse = envelope[:body][:create_response]
p createresponse 
    if createresponse[:overall_status] == "OK"
        p 'Success' 
        results = createresponse[:results]
        if !results.kind_of?(Array)
            results = [results]
        end 
        results.each {|result| p "Subscriber: #{result[:object][:id]} #{result[:object][:email_address]}"}
    end 
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Mac This is great! For the creds file what are you expecting in there? Having a hard time finding the right info for the wsdl to use and the endpoint.

Comment: I created a repo with this example which has an example creds.rb file: https://github.com/MichaelAllenClark/exacttarget-soap-ruby.  The WSDL/Endpoint vary for different accounts so you may need to contact support to confirm which stack you are on. Quick rule that works most of the time is to find your numeric account ID.  If it is 7 digits and starts with a 1, that is S4. If 7 digits and starts with 6 or 7, that is S6. Otherwise S1. This help page has a list of the URLs: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/getting_started_developers_and_the_exacttarget_api/

Comment: One other question here @Mac. What's the easiest way to add the subscriber to multiple lists? Can I just do:

`
subscriber['Lists'] = [{'ID' => '1719338'}, {'ID' => '1719339'}, {'ID' => '1719340'}]
`

Comment: Yes, that looks correct.

Comment: I am now getting a response from the server telling me `Savon::SOAPFault - (q0:Security) Login failed:`. The username and password in your example is this just what we use for code.exacttarget.com or what auth info is this looking for here, @Mac?

Comment: It would be the same credentials you use to login to https://members.exacttarget.com or https://mc.exacttarget.com.  It is different than the Code@ login.

Comment: Thanks. So many different logins. I also made an app in app center and had API keys. Not sure what all is used for what. Wish the docs made this more clear for us.

Comment: Looks like there are different account types for this also as I am now getting: Savon::SOAPFault - (soap:Client) User not authorized:.

Comment: There are 2 permissions that need to be set for a user to access the API. 'API Access' and 'Grant the user access to the web services' which can be selected by logging into ExactTarget then going to Email(If logging into Marketing Cloud), then Admin, then Users, then Edit.

Comment: thanks for all the help! I have been able to successfully signup users! As for Unsubscribing them is that by passing new options as seen [here](https://github.com/MichaelAllenClark/exacttarget-soap-ruby/blob/master/samples/create_subscriber.rb#L23)?

What options do you pass if so?

Comment: what changes do you suggest for unsubscribing a user from a list? @Mac

Comment: There is a Status property at the list level which can be set to Active or Unsubscribed so instead of: subscriber['Lists'] = {'ID' => '1719338'}
It would be subscriber['Lists'] = {'ID' => '1719338', 'Status' => 'Unsubscribed'}

Comment: Thanks @Mac, I unfortunately keep getting an error saying "The subscriber is already on the list" when I do this. Any ideas?

Comment: The payload seems to be 100% correct also.

`<tns:CreateRequest>
<tns:Objects xsi:type="tns:Subscriber">
<tns:EmailAddress>newrd@blah.com</tns:EmailAddress>
<tns:Lists><tns:ID>18315088</tns:ID>
<tns:Status>Unsubscribed</tns:Status></tns:Lists></tns:Objects><tns:Options></tns:Options></tns:CreateRequest>`

Comment: That is because it is a CreateRequest which by default won't update existing records. Check the example at https://github.com/MichaelAllenClark/exacttarget-soap-ruby/blob/master/samples/create_subscriber.rb which has a line where it sets the opts variable that turns it into an UpdateAdd (Upsert).

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this documentation](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/adding_subscribers_to_a_list/) - here is the SOAP payload you would want to get to  -

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>  
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">YOURACCESSTOKEN</fueloauth>
    </Header>  
    <Body>
        <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Objects xsi:type="Subscriber">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                <EmailAddress>help@example.com</EmailAddress>
                <SubscriberKey>help@example.com</SubscriberKey>
                <EmailTypePreference>HTML</EmailTypePreference>
                <Attributes>
                    <Name>First Name</Name>
                    <Value>John</Value>
                </Attributes>
                <Attributes>
                    <Name>Last Name</Name>
                    <Value>Smith</Value>
                </Attributes>
                <Lists>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ID>12345</ID>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Status>Active</Status>
                </Lists>
                <Status>Active</Status>
            </Objects>
        </CreateRequest>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

This should get you started.

For more information regarding the `fuelOAuth` property, check out [this post](http://kellyjandrews.com/using-fuel-oauth2-with-the-soap-api/).